# grep all Bean.java files(case insensitive) in a directory for a particular strings(multiple)

Tags: linux, grep

How would I search all Bean.java files(Case Insensitive) for a simple multiple strings(i.e "getString","formatHTMLDetailMessage","getHTMLText") (not a regex) in the current directory and all sub-directories on Linux OS? I just want to print a list of file and directory names that match all 3 strings.

Answer (score -1):

```
grep -l -r -i string1 ./ > tmp1.txt
cat tmp1.txt | xargs grep -l -r -i string2 ./ > tmp2.txt
cat tmp2.txt | xargs grep -l -r -i string3
```